# Store returned values in variable

Tags: return

I've got a code which renames the names of files to randomly chosen numbers. The code works, but I can't seem to figure out how to store the original filenames and the respective renamed filename (random number).
When I run the code, I only get the values of the last iteration using 'return'. But how do I store the original filenames and the respective renamed filenames?

So, I want to have a list of 'file_name' (which contains all the original filenames) and 'rand_keynumber' (which are the generated random numbers)

Thank you.

```
import os
import random


numbers = range(1,1025)
numbers_list = list(map(str,numbers))


def keynumber():
    # Generate a random index
    rand_index = random.randint(0, len(numbers_list)-1)

    # Get the keynumber
    global rand_keynumber
    rand_keynumber = numbers_list[rand_index]

    # Remove the used-up keynumber from the list to
    # prevent randomly selecting it again when renaming
    numbers_list.remove(rand_keynumber)
    return rand_keynumber


def renam_name():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\samwi\OneDrive\Bureaublad\videos_anonimisatie\video_to_rename")
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\samwi\OneDrive\Bureaublad\videos_anonimisatie\video_to_rename")
    global file_name
    for f in file_list:
        # get the file extension
        file_name, img_type = os.path.splitext(f)   

        os.rename(f, keynumber() + img_type)
    return file_name
    

renam_name()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are assigning a new value to the global file_name variable on each iteration. You need to append each filename and the selected key number to a list before moving to the next file in file_list.

```
import os
import random

numbers = range(1,1025)
numbers_list = list(map(str,numbers))

file_names = []

def keynumber():
    # Generate a random index
    rand_index = random.randint(0, len(numbers_list)-1)

    # Get the keynumber
    rand_keynumber = numbers_list[rand_index]

    # Remove the used-up keynumber from the list to
    # prevent randomly selecting it again when renaming
    numbers_list.remove(rand_keynumber)
    return rand_keynumber


def renam_name():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\samwi\OneDrive\Bureaublad\videos_anonimisatie\video_to_rename")
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\samwi\OneDrive\Bureaublad\videos_anonimisatie\video_to_rename")
    for f in file_list:
        # get the file extension
        next_file_name, img_type = os.path.splitext(f)
        next_keynumber = keynumber()   

        file_names.append([next_file_name, next_keynumber])
        os.rename(f, next_keynumber + img_type)
    

renam_name()
```

Comment: I guess I'm curious about your use of global here. I don't see your initial declaration of file_name. If you declared it as an empty list at the global scope, you don't need global at the function level since you are just modifying a mutable object and for that matter don't need to return it since it is accessible globally.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an empty array under import random and in your functions just before returning rand_keynumber and file_name, append what you want to the empty array using .append

Comment: Hello. I've added an empty list `rand_keynumber_final = []` after import. And I've added     `rand_keynumber_final.append(rand_keynumber)` just before return. But I get the following error: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list